# Teclado virtual en un JFrame

Tags: java, netbeans, java-swing, formularios

Buenas amigos

Necesito ayuda con un formulario que usa un teclado virtual, dicho teclado se encuentra en un `jPanel` , de momento solo lo he podido programar para que el texto sea introducido en un solo `jTextFIeld`, estoy buscando la manera de que el teclado pueda escribir en cualquiera de los `jTextField` que he puesto en el formulario.

Espero haberme explicado bien y de ante mano muchas gracias!!

[Vista del jFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f2rKD.png)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
private void b1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt){
    String A = campo1.getText();
    campo1.setText(A + "1");
}
```

este es el código que le asigne a cada botón al momento de hacer click en el

Comment: Debes añadir el código relevante para que podamos ayudarte,en concreto el código que reacciona a la pulsación del boton y que escribe en el textfield. Puedes pasarte por [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En mi opinión yo usaría una variable de control que indicase que `jTextFIeld` tiene supuestamente el foco.

Cuando pulsase sobre un botón del teclado virtual, haría un switch de esa variable para saber sobre que `jTextFIeld` escribir.

Tengo Java un poco oxidado y no recuerdo el nombre de los eventos para cuando un componente recibe el foco, pero a ver si con este ejemplo te puedes hacer una idea de lo que te comento:

```
String fieldActivo = "jTextField1";

private void jTextField1_Focus() {
    fieldActivo = "jTextField1";
}

private void jTextField2_Focus() {
    fieldActivo = "jTextField2";
}

private void jTextField3_Focus() {
    fieldActivo = "jTextField3";
}

private void jTextField4_Focus() {
    fieldActivo = "jTextField4";
}

private void b1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt){

    JTextField field;
    switch (fieldActivo)
    {
        case "jTextField1": field = jTextField1; break;
        case "jTextField2": field = jTextField2; break;
        case "jTextField3": field = jTextField3; break;
        case "jTextField4": field = jTextField4; break;
    }

    String A = field.getText();
    field.setText(A + "1");
}
```

Comment: Buenas noches amigo
en la línea de código

**private void b1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt){**

** JTextField field;**

**switch (fieldActivo){**


A que haces referencia?

Comment: Al comienzo del código cree una variable de tipo String que pertenece a la clase para guardar que campo hizo el último foco. Después, dentro del evento que tu creaste, defino una variable de tipo JTextField que según el switch le asignaré el JTextField correspondiente. A continuación después del switch, sería como tu pusiste pero especificando el JTextField que hemos creado internamente en la función

Comment: Cierto amigo, apenas tuve oportunidad de implementarlo y funciono
te lo agradezco!!